# How to diable webview zoom property in corona?

Tags: webview, coronasdk

I need to disable web view zoom property in my application. Is it possible to enable/disable zoom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Add this code to your html page:

```
<head>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
```

To enable the zoom just create a copy of the same page but without meta tags:

```
<head>

</head>
```

then load the page in web view.

Comment: does this still work? Its not making a difference in my app :(